# How to install libGL.so.1 in windows10 linux console (called Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, matplotlib, windows-10, conda

I use the "Ubuntu" app in the W10 store to install anaconda etc. This provides convenient Linux support on a W10 system. I installed anaconda and use the jupyter notebook from the Linux terminal. Importing pylab however gives the error

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

One way to fix this would be to install libGL.so.1 obviously which might be in the package lib `libgl1-mesa-glx`. However,

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx --yes > output

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglapi-mesa_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is there a way to install libGL.so.1 or use pylab with out it?

Comment: For now I can import the functions that I need from Numpy, but it would be great to have full compatibility in W10 Linux console.

Comment: `apt` shows error 404, because the file is not on the server. What is at this URL are files ending in `ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb`. So your package list is probably out of date, which is usually updated by `apt-get update`